# Why aren't my stored procedures being listed after DBScaffold (.Net Core MVC)

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I would like to run a parametrized stored procedure that lists movies based on a genre name (or ID). I've tried to do this in many ways, but I always end up falling short. Basically, my stored procedures are not being listed under the models after I have scaffolded dbset.

I've followed the first six steps in [this link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-core-entity-framework-call-store-procedure/)

1. Create stored procedure
2. Created ASP.NET Core MVC Project (I used MVC - the author did not, but I assume this should be fine still)
3. Built solution
4. Installed SQL Server packages (Tools, SQL Server, Designer)
5. Scaffolded database using the following code:

   ```
   Scaffold-DbContext "Server=SQL SERVER (e.g localhost);Database=DATABASE (e.g db_core_sp_call);Trusted_Connection=True;user id=SQL USERNAME;password=SQL PASSWORD;"
       Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 
       -OutputDir Models/DB
   ```

These steps are seemingly successful, except for the fact that my stored procedures are not listed. Does anyone have suggestions about what I should do here? I've tried to do this in different ways as well. This was seemed the most straightforward but I can't get past step 5.

Answer (score 0):

In .net core scaffolding is used to scaffold SQL tables to entities. There is a no option to scaffold the stored procedures, but you can execute stored procedures. Tracking issue: [stored procedure mapping support](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/245) is open issue.

If you require to execute stored procedure with parameters.

For executing raw SQL queries:

```
var students = _dbContext.Students.FromSql("EXECUTE dbo.GetStudents {0}",studentId).ToList();
```

If you require to execute insert/update/delete command in your stored procedure then use the `ExecuteSqlCommand` method.

```
_dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("InsertStudents @id,@name",
                          new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@id", studentId),
                          new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@name", name));
```

This way you can execute your stored procedure in ASP.NET Core; I hope it should help you. Let me know if you require any more information. :)